# How to bind angular template with kendo chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to bind the template below code:

```
var template = '<div kendo-chart k-legend="{ position: "right" }" k-series-defaults="{ type: "line" }" k-series="[{ name: "Budget", field: "budget" },{ name: "Spending", field: "spending" }]" k-category-axis="{ field: "unit" }" k-data-source="[{"unit":"Sales","budget":"40000","spending":"52800"},{"unit":"Marketing","budget":"20000","spending":"42000"},{"unit":"Development","budget":"60000","spending":"21400"},{"unit":"Customer Support","budget":"30000","spending":"28500"},{"unit":"IT","budget":"25000","spending":"18900"},{"unit":"Administration","budget":"10000","spending":"11100"}]" k-series-hover="onSeriesHover" style="height: 250px;" ></div>
```

but i am getting error while appending this template.

Error code:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {position:
```

this is the code for append:

```
$compile(controlContent)(scope);
element.append(controlContent);
```

Comment: escape qutoes(`"`)...

Comment: @kukkuz - can you please provide any example or please change one place of my code and rest i will do.

Comment: sure, escape using \ like this:  `'<div kendo-chart k-legend="{ position: \"right\" }" ....'` maybe that's the issue here..

Comment: @kukkuz - Thank you very much. It's working now